# variatons on the standard Basis of $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

> let n $\ge$ 2. For all $i=1,...n$ we denote $v_i$ as the vector in $\Bbb R^n$ where $v_i := (1,...,0,...,1)$. Show that $(v_1,...,v_n)$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^n$.

So this is a standard Basis, but with 0's in the places of the 1's and the other way around too.

My attempt at solving this:

I must show that
$$\lambda_1 \begin{pmatrix}
            0 \\
            \vdots \\
            1 \\
            \vdots \\
            1\\
            \end{pmatrix} 
+...+ \lambda_i \begin{pmatrix}
            1 \\
            \vdots \\
            0 \\
            \vdots \\
            1\\
            \end{pmatrix} 
+...+ \lambda_n \begin{pmatrix}
            1 \\
            \vdots \\
            1 \\
            \vdots \\
            0\\
            \end{pmatrix} 
=           \begin{pmatrix}
            \ell_1 \\
            \vdots \\
            \ell_i \\
            \vdots \\
            \ell_n\\
            \end{pmatrix} $$
for all permutations of $\ell_1,...,\ell_n \in \Bbb R$. (in other words, the span of such vectors is $\Bbb R^n$)

I can create a new vector $w:= v_1+...+v_n=\begin{pmatrix}
            n-1 \\
            \vdots \\
            n-1 \\
            \vdots \\
            n-1\\
            \end{pmatrix}$

And so, with Steinitz's theorem we have
$$span(v_1,...v_n)=span(v_1,...,v_n,w) $$
Which, according to my intuition, should make things easier, but I don't know how to proceed from here. Am I on the right track? And then how do I go on to show that these family of vectors is linearly independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that $v_1, ..., v_n$ are linearly independent. You can use that method to get *easier  to work with*-vectors, for example,  you can try to prove $\{v_1, v_2 - v_1, ..., v_n - v_1\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Ok, here is my try at that,
I arranged the resulting vectors into an augmented Matrix and what I want to do now is show that there are only trivial results that satisfy it. We have
$$          \left[
    \begin{array}{cccccc|c}
            0 & 1  & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 &0 \\
            1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 &0 \\
            1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \vdots \\
            \vdots & \vdots & & \ddots & & \vdots \\
            1 & 0 & \ \cdots & & & -1 &0
            \end{array}
\right] $$ 
If this would be a finite matrix it would be easy to solve, but I am a bit puzzled here

Comment: The matrix is finite, given a fixed $n$. You can try to prove that the determinant is not zero, which implies that the only solution is the zero vector. Hint: sum to the first row every other one.

Comment: Aha! I got it now, thanks!

Comment: One other question. Could I not just have shown that this family can be put as a Linear combinaion of the Standart Basis? For example $v_1$ would be a sum of all $e_i$ Starting at i = 2 all the way to n, and generalize to a formula to get any $v_1$ ? That seems more clear and easier

Comment: Yes, you're correct and that's actually pretty straight forward to do with this particular ser of vectors. The previous approach is more general, though.